# How do I mount an SD card?

Tags: mount, osx

My SD card will suddenly not automount. It works on another Mac.

Can someone provide a solution to mount with Terminal?

```
$ diskutil list

/dev/disk2
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *16.0 GB    disk2
1:             Windows_FAT_32 NO NAME                 16.0 GB    disk2s1
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are using mac os x due to the "mac" remark, please add that info, including OS version, and the laptop model or if you are using a sd to usb adapter. This will help troubleshoot the issue. Do you want to fix the automount or simply mount manually?

Answer (score 2):

Simply `mount /dev/disk2s1 /foo`  Where `/foo` is an empty directory where you want to access the card.  The normal mount point for disks on a mac is within `/Volumes` <del>but since it isn't auto-mounting, you will need to create a directory somewhere</del>.  Don't mount it directly to `/Volumes` or you won't be able to access your HD, including your OS.  You could mount it to your home directory even, below /mnt represents a directory that you've created, in this example, it's in your home directory:

```
$ sudo mkdir ~/mnt
$ sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk2s1 ~/mnt
$ cd ~/mnt
```

(of course if you are in your home directory you can leave out the `~/` if you want.)

You can also use the `diskutil` command.  `man diskutil` to learn more about it. Are you running the same version of OS X on both machines?  There are reported issues with FAT32 on Yosemite.

Comment: $ mkdir /mnt mount /dev/disk2s1 /mnt cd /mnt
mkdir: /mnt: Permission denied
mkdir: mount: File exists
mkdir: /dev/disk2s1: File exists
mkdir: /mnt: Permission denied
mkdir: cd: File exists
mkdir: /mnt: Permission denied

Comment: both machines are running 10.10.1

Comment: @earthling, try `sudo !!`
You must sudo mkdir and mount
also, the new lines did not save in my post, those are separate lines.

Comment: sudo mount /dev/disk2s1 ~/mnt                                    
mount: You must specify a filesystem type with -t

Comment: @earthling, you don't have to, most linuxes can figure it out, I have rarely specified it and never had a problem.

Comment: that entire line was a 'quote' return line from 'bash.' will not let me proceed without a 'filesystem type.'

Comment: @earthling, OK, my bad, I said "most linuxes can figure it out", without even realizing that you're not on linux your on OS X.  Linux guesses, Mac OS X does not.
On a mac use: `-t msdos`

Comment: sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk2s1 ~/mnt
/System/Library/Extensions/msdosfs.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) not loadable (reason unspecified); check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
mount_msdos: msdos filesystem is not available

Comment: I am using Yosemite and it cannot mount a SD Card of Partition Type: Windows_FAT_32 ...

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by running:

```bash
brew cask install osxfuse
brew install ext4fuse
sudo mkdir /Volumes/rpi
sudo ext4fuse /dev/disk2s2 /Volumes/rpi -o allow_other
sudo ls /Volumes/rpi
```

Solution described:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13437/how-to-mount-a-raspbian-sd-card-on-a-mac

**Update** (as of osxfuse 4)

```bash
brew install macfuse
brew install ext4fuse
mkdir /Volumes/rpi
ext4fuse /dev/disk2s2 /Volumes/rpi -o allow_other
```

[ext4fuse Github page](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse)

Comment: Note: it's now "macfuse", you can install it with `brew install macfuse`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm updating the answer